# Extract key name from single element dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

If I know my dictionaries will always have a single element, is there a way to extract the key name without going through a list?  I'm currently doing it this way.

```
data = {'foo': [1, 2, 3]}
key_name = data.keys()[0]
```

Is there a more efficient technique?

Comment: If your dictionary only has a single element, it might not be the best data structure for the job.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense +1 for thinking beyond the question.

Comment: Actually, I just came up with this issue  I am creating dictionary entries with a function, so I am returning a single element dictionary from the function (to be included in an aggregated dictionary).  I may modify the function to return key,data, but I still think the question is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating dictionary yields keys.

Using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

```
>>> data = {'foo': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> next(iter(data))
'foo'
```

---

Benchmark:

```
In [1]: data = {'foo': [1, 2, 3]}

In [2]: %timeit next(iter(data))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 197 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit data.keys()[0]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 155 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit data.iterkeys().next()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 226 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit k, = data.keys()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 151 ns per loop

In [10]: %timeit k, = data    # <--- fastest
10000000 loops, best of 3: 81.4 ns per loop
```

Comment: Is a generator more efficient than referencing the list index?

Comment: @bholben, I added a benchmark to the answer. `data.keys()[0]` was fastest.

Comment: @falsetru,  how about ` k, = data.keys()`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I updated the answer with `k, = data.keys()` and `k, = data` (As I mentioned in my answer, iterating dictionary yields keys). `k, = data` was the fastest.

Comment: @falsetru, Nice!  `key_name, = data` is *faster* and *cleaner* than `key_name = data.keys()[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `iterkeys`:

```
data.iterkeys().next()
'foo'
```

Presuming you are using `python 2`

For `python2` or `python 3`

```
k, = data.keys()
print (k)
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll also need the value at some point, the most "pythonic" and robust way would probably be to use a **try...except** block like this:

```
data = {'foo': [1, 2, 3]}
try:
    key, value = data.items()[0]
except IndexError:
    raise Exception("Your dictionary didn't have the element you thought it had")
```

Here, you're simply converting your dictionary into a list of 2-tuples (using `items`) and picking out the first one of these, catching the case where there are no items. If the dictionary does have more than one item, any of the *key:value* pairs might be returned and your results will be indeterminate.

Without discussing your specific use case -- which you are obviously far more familiar with than I -- it's worth pointing out that even when you expect a data structure to have particular contents, there will almost always be edge cases where that assumption is false and handling those exceptions gracefully will make for more robust code.

This code should work in both Python 2 and 3 and given that in your regular case there is only one item available, the `iteritems` method will give negligible advantage in Python 2 over its standard counterpart, `items`.

**Edit:**

To expand on this point of efficiency (`items` vs `iteritems` in Python 2) the following (quick and dirty) timings show a very slight advantage of the former over the latter:

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit "data = {'foo': [1, 2, 3]}; _ = data.items()[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.316 usec per loop
$ python2.7 -m timeit "data = {'foo': [1, 2, 3]}; _ = next(data.iteritems())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.377 usec per loop
```

Furthermore, extracting both the key and value at the same time gives a slight extra saving over taking one at a time.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Maybe this is not a direct answer, however the sentiment is very helpful for new developers like myself.